# Are iPhone 'standard' sounds (e.g. shutter, email sent) available for use?

Tags: iphone

I was hoping to make use of the sounds that Apple has created for its applications, like the sound that is played when the camera's shutter is fired.

It appears that these sounds aren't available for usage from within the SDK.  Is this accurate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a way; you have to get them from the SDK (the demos) and *put* them in your application.